# Truly destroying a PHP Session?

Tags: php, session

I have heard mixed responses on this topic, so what is a sure fire way to destroy a PHP session?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['foo'];
   ...
}
session_destroy();
```

In the most simple of cases, would this sufficient to truly terminate the session between the user and the server?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648565/destroying-php-session/10662060#10662060

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To destroy a session you should take the following steps:

- delete the session data
- invalidate the session ID

To do this, I’d use this:

```
session_start();
// resets the session data for the rest of the runtime
$_SESSION = array();
// sends as Set-Cookie to invalidate the session cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) { 
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', 1, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], isset($params['httponly']));
}
session_destroy();
```

And to be sure that the session ID is invalid, you should only allow session IDs that were being initiated by your script. So set a flag and check if it is set:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    // invalidate old session data and ID
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
}
```

Additionally, you can use this timestamp to swap the session ID periodically to reduce its lifetime:

```
if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but you just answered like 3 questions in one answer for me.  Thank you!

Comment: In your first example on line 5, instead of `$_COOKIES` it should be `$_COOKIE`, otherwise you might wonder why it's never destroying the session cookie since `isset($_COOKIES[session_name()])` would never evaluate to true.

Comment: @Gumbo following your advices, finally I was able to remove the session cookie... Anyway, is there some recent way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Manual addresses this question.

You need to kill the session and also remove the session cookie (if you are using cookies).

See this page (especially the first example):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

In the one site I've made where I did use PHP sessions, I never actually destroy the session.

The problem is that you pretty much have to call `session_start()` to check for your `$_SESSION` variables, at which point, lo and behold, you've created another session anyway.

Hence on my site I just made sure that *every* page called `session_start()`, and then just `unset()` those parts of the session state that matter when the user logs off.

Comment: Thanks for input Alnitak, this is what I suspected with calling session_start() on every page.  I'll just continue to unset the variables as they are used.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SESSION = [];
@unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
session_destroy();
```