# Logut Session not destroyed

Tags: php, session

I created a log out page and calling it through a href link but it not working the session was not destroying. Help me, the code n link are below.

logout.php

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php"); 
 ?>
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226040/is-this-a-proper-way-to-destroy-all-sessions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the file is on same server.
2. Write this code on the very top of everything else.
3. Additionally  use this code

   ```
   session_unset();
   session_write_close();
   ```
4. session_destroy only destroys session on server end not the cookies, make sure you are not using cookies, if yes then see below code

To Set cookie

```
setcookie("cookieName", $value, time()+3600);
```

To Unset Cookie

```
setcookie("cookieName", $value, time()-36000);
```

More details about session: [PHP: session_destroy - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to regenerate the session ID:

`session_regenerate_id();`