# What is the right way to unset or destroy a particular session?

Tags: php, session

I have a session like this: `$_SESSION['mycatalogue']['user']`

When I unset, I do this: `unset($_SESSION['mycatalogue'])`

What I want to know is, are all of the following meant to do the same thing:
`unset($_SESSION['mycatalogue'])`

`unset($_SESSION['mycatalogue']['user'])`

`$_SESSION['mycatalogue']['user'] = ""`

So when I am unsetting a session or assigning NULL to it, it still keeps the arrays in memory?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a proper way to destroy all sessions in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226040/is-this-a-proper-way-to-destroy-all-sessions-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697822/session-unset-or-session-destroy

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clear about session concept. Your session is this `$_SESSION['mycatalogue']`. `['user']` is a index in your session names as `mycatalogue`.

If you want to unset a particular index from your session then use like

```
 unset($_SESSION['mycatalogue']['user'])
```

It is as same as you unset an index of array.

```
 $_SESSION['mycatalogue']['user'] = ""
```

will not unset your index `user` in your session. It will just set it as empty.

```
unset($_SESSION['mycatalogue'])
```

will unset your all session named as `mycatalogue`.

[session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) will unset your all data related to current session but not unset any global variable

Answer (score -1):

Unset will destroy a particular session variable whereas session_destroy() will destroy all the session data for that user.

It really depends on your application as to which one you should use. Just keep the above in mind.

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data

session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user.
```