# How to LOG OUT all active logged in users in php from admin side

Tags: php, apache, session, authentication, logout

I want to add something like Logout all active Logins in to my system from administrators

I have some case when Admin changes in permission of users , I am storing permissions in SESSION ,

So I want to make log out all the users when ADMIN Press event

Something like in Google we have option that log out from other devices.

one way I can find that I can set one GLOBAL variable and every time I will check it when I fire AJAX in every 1 min after log-in

is there another way to do this which is more standard .

Comment: are you storing every user login session in your database (session table ) ?.. if so then u can play with it ..

Comment: Maybe this answer suits your case - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5195081/3240813

Comment: @chintan-gor your problem solved or not.

Answer (score 1):

you should identify where the user's sessions are stored.
If your web server is using files (see your php.ini) then deleting this files will make a brutal destroy of all the user's sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario where I needed to force logout the user via PHP.

C.Vergnaud suggestion worked fine but just to complement his answer, look for `session.save_path` inside the file `php.ini`.

Alternatively, you may use the function `session_save_path()` to get this path from PHP.