# Is there a way to delete all sessions/clear all identities at the same itme?

Tags: zend-framework2

There was an error that corrupted a bunch of users' sessions and I'm wondering if there's a way to remove/reset all sessions without making them all go through our logout script.

I'd like something that does what this does

```
$auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');                               
if($auth->hasIdentity()) {          
    $auth->clearIdentity();             
}
```

but for every existing user session.

Comment: It's not a ZF2 specific function, take a look at the answers here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193744/how-to-kill-a-all-php-sessions

Comment: @Crisp I tried those first of course, but it didn't destroy my sessions at all.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to clear all sessions is probably to delete all session files manually from your server.