# How to destroy all session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I created a chat app without database using session
this is my chat.php, called using rest api

```
$sid = $_GET["s"];
$new_name = $_GET["name"];
$new_msg = $_GET["msg"];
$client_length = $_GET["le"];
session_id($sid); //session
session_start(); //start session
$session_id = session_id();
if(empty($_SESSION['chat']))
{
    $_SESSION["chat"] = array("0" => array(
        "createdAt" => date("Y-m-d H:i:sa"),
        "name" => "Room ".$sid,
        "sid" => $sid));
}
array_push($_SESSION["chat"], array("name" => $new_name, "msg"=>$new_msg));
exit(json_encode($_SESSION["chat"]));
```

I want to free memory every 12 hours with destroy or clear all session
so when initiate 
    session_id($sid); //session
    session_start(); //start session
the `$_SESSION['chat']` back to empty, and also memory is free.

how to destroy or clear all session or `session_id()` in php

sorry what i mean not `session_destroy()`

i want to make a `task` or `job` in php check if 12 hours after last reset of session, it will reset again and again.

in this case maybe you will think about `session_destroy` it only happend if program knows the `session_id` and already `session_start`.
what if the program dont know about that, and want to **reset** the program's session?

that i mean

CMIIW about `session_id` and `session_start`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a/all php sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193744/how-to-kill-a-all-php-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

finally I use `echo  session_save_path();` and delete session file in that folder